# Octave crashes running a script that used to run with no issues

Tags: crash, octave, octave-gui

I am currenctly having an issue. I have a code which I was running multiple times in a row couple days ago, even a few hours ago. While I am trying to run it now octave crashes every time! I have changed nothing in my code. I  get no output while I used to. The gnu console disappears and the program crashes. I tried to clear workspace and everything but I still ger the same. I even tried downloading the latest octave version. At first it worked, I run it multiple times without issues but now it will not run till the end again.

I would expect to get the prints I was getting a few hours ago while I changed nothing and it crashes

Comment: That is a tough problem. But what is your question? What are you looking for when you tell this story here? This is not the site to get sympathy, Stack Overflow collects questions and answers about programming.

Comment: If you have not done so please consider posting over to the primary support forum at octave.discourse.group where they may be able to help you debug this problem.  One quick thought, are you running windows 11? a recent windows update has changed the default terminal used by windows programs and it is causing many problems with Octave. If this is the case there is workaround in the meantime: you can change the default terminal back to the (older) Windows console host using the settings shown at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/

Answer (score 1):

Nick' suggestion solved my problem

> One quick thought, are you running windows 11? a recent windows update has changed the default terminal used by windows programs and it is causing many problems with Octave. If this is the case there is workaround in the meantime: you can change the default terminal back to the (older) Windows console host using the settings shown at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/

Changing the default terminal app to 'Windows Console Host' solved my problem

Comment: glad this worked for you.  a permanent fix is still pending.  for anyone else finding this report, see the following discourse post addressing the topic   https://octave.discourse.group/t/workaround-for-weird-behavior-of-command-window-widget-in-windows/4981